# Modify dishwasher water inlet valve or harness

Tags: water, dishwasher

Original water inlet valve electrical harness hookup
[image]

Replacement water inlet valve electrical harness hookup
[image]

Male connector/harness
[image]

Inlet valve with female connector
[image]

Dishwasher model number etc.
[image]

My dishwasher has a slow leak coming from the water inlet valve (water constantly drips into the dishwasher).  I ordered a replacement water inlet valve (W10158389).  The replacement is identical to the original in all ways except three.  The female end on the inlet valve is reversed (rotated 180 degrees), is gray instead of green and worst of all has a slight different shaped and so the harness wont snap in.

Photo one is of the female connector on the original valve - note it looks like a “T”.

Photo two is the female connector on the replacement valve - note it looks like a “l”.

I imagine that I can fix this problem by simply breaking off the tab on the replacement valve or on the male end of the harness.

Breaking the tab will allow the electrical harness to snap in but I am worried that the polarity might be switched.

I have contacted the parts manufacturer (repair clinic - the official parts supply house for kitchen aid dishwashers) who confirmed it was the correct part and who mentioned that parts can change slightly over time (this dishwasher is from ~2008).  I have also contacted a seller of whirlpool parts (whirlpool makes this part) on Amazon who also confirmed this is the correct part and that all the modern replacement parts of model #W10158389 will be identical.

Any advice on how to modify this part would be most welcome.

Comment: Can you please post a picture of the male plug? Also, the distance between the electrical contacts appears to be different on the two female sockets; can you confirm?

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it - thanks for your questions.  I have added a photo of the male plug.  The distance between the metal contacts are the same on the original and replacement parts (they just look different in the images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with what I ended up doing (for posterity) in case someone else stumbles on this with the same problem.

I carefully cut away the small plastic parts inside the plug so that it would fit and it has been working with no problem for many months.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to close this out, and congrats on making it work!

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the existing plug off the old one and fit it to the new one so it assembles correctly.

You should be able to identify which wire is where when comparing the old and new.

Edit update:
Remove the male plug on the harness.
Extend wires as necessary.
Purchase two crimp-on (insulated) terminals that fit the new pump, fit and test.

Comment: Unfortunately the male connector/harness itself (i.e. the connector that comes from the main dishwasher control unit) is not included with the replacement valve.  Additionally, the female plug attached to the replacement valve cannot be removed and swapped with the female plug from the original valve.

Comment: @Han the old plug on the old valve can be removed by cutting the wires. The new incorrect plug can be removed by cutting the wires. Then the old plug can be fitted to the new valve by joining the wires. If this is outside your skillset then get a professional.

Comment: I agree with @Solar Mike on this.  No need to duplicate his answer.

Comment: @Solar Mike there is no way that I see to remove the female plug from the original valve - it is an integral part of the solenoid body (see added photo above or parts photo here: https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Water-Inlet-Valve/WPW10158389/1481085).  Additionally, to get an updated male plug I would have to buy a complete wiring harness that costs > $100.

Comment: @Han see update to answer.

Comment: @Solar Mike is it possible to attach the wires to the wrong terminals (i.e. reverse polarity)?  Also, you mention testing - other than simply running the dishwasher, are there any tests to do to make sure that the replacement is correct (i.e. right specifications) despite the difference in the updated plug?

Answer (score 0):

**Easier way to clear the two pins of the new dishwasher inlet valve so they can clip to the Control Panel connector**

Notice the gray plastic piece surrounding the two male pins in the new pump assembly.  You can see the identifying number "R25/2-2" . This is the same as the connector on my new valve, from Supco, identified as WV8389, "can replace W10158389".

My existing green connector coming from the dishwasher control panel would not fit the two pins because it could not reach them. The grey plastic around the male pins blocks them, and looks solidly attached to the solenoid. But it pulls off.

**Grasp the grey plastic with small pliers, and pull**

The grey plastic comes right off, leaving two sides of the clip and the male terminals. The existing green connector from the Kenmore control panel snaps right in.

For those wanting to test the new valve, **make up a inlet water valve test rig**, to bring 120AC to the valve connection.

Cut an extension cord, leaving the wall plug and two wires. Strip the ends of the wires. There's a long description online of attaching spade lugs to all the wires to connect them....too complicated. **Get the wonderful Wago clip connectors**. Fifty cents each, but absolutely foolproof. Cut the leads coming from the control panel to the connector. Now, insert each lead of the connector into a Wago connector. Insert each wire to the wall plug into a Wago connector. You have a test rig. Plug into new inlet valve. Don't power it until you've connected the water supply hose, and turned on the water.  Now, plug in the test rig, listen to the solenoid click, and watch a wonderful strong stream of water come out of the valve. Be careful not to let the water touch the electricity.

And now use your two Wago connectors to reconnect the green connector to the control panel, where you clipped it.